# can a visual studio extension be used directly by a t4 template?

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-extensions

Currently I have a t4 template that is generating code using a helper class.  I want to distribute this to other people though, but I need to provide the dll so that the template can actually run.  I'd really rather not rewrite the code in the helper class as t4 template code though.

I was thinking I could do it as a visual studio extension though.  But although I know how to normally add the assembly reference in a t4 template to my helper.dll, I'm not sure how to reference the extension code from it if it's an extension instead.  Is it even possible?

All I'm trying to do is have the template code call helper.DoitsThing().  (simplified for clarity)

I would assume it would be possible.    I'd be surprised if no one ever needed to do this.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a visual studio extension, which using helper.dll to generate t4 Template? Or create a Visual Studio item template that generates from a T4 template?

Comment: What I was looking to do was have a t4 template call a method in a dll or extension but to do that with a helper.dll requires hardcoding the location of the assembly.  I want to be able to distribute this code.  So my thought was to use an extension but I'm not sure a t4 template can directly call an extension method.

Comment: Do you mean that t4 template directly call an visual studio vsix package api method, or c# extension method?

Comment: Yes, Cole.  That's exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: I provide two options, the first one, or the second?

Comment: cole, either option.  Either option would be great.